# When Use PUT or PATCH For Updating Data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to edit some information which is retrieved from the DB, at the `edit.blade.php`:

```
<form action="{{ route('updateWallet', ['id'=>$wallet->id]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf          

    <label for="title" class="control-label">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title-shop" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{ $wallet->title }}" autofocus>
    
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="cachable" value="cashable" id="cacheStatus" @php if(($wallet->is_cachable) == 1) {echo 'checked';} @endphp>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="cacheStatus">
    &nbsp; With Cash
    </label>
    
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="activaton" value="active" id="activationStatus" @php if(($wallet->is_active) == 1) {echo 'checked';} @endphp>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="activationStatus">
    &nbsp; Active
    </label>
    
    <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And the route for this goes here:

```
Route::post('wallets/update/{wallet}','Wallet\WalletController@update')->name('updateWallet');
```

Then at the Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, Wallet $wallet)
    {
        try {
            $data = $request->validate([
                'title' => 'required',
                'activation' => 'nullable',
                'cachable' => 'nullable'
            ]);

            $wallet->title = $data['title'];

            if (!empty($data['activation'])) {
                $wallet->is_active = 1;
            } else {
                $wallet->is_active = 0;
            }

            if (!empty($data['cachable'])) {
                $wallet->is_cachable = 1;
            } else {
                $wallet->is_cachable = 0;
            }

            $wallet->save();
            flash()->overlay('Updated!', 'Your data edited successfully.', 'success');
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
        }
        return redirect(url('admin/wallets/index'));
    }
```

It works fine and perfect since I'm not adding any method name in the blade.

But when I try this, I get this error:

```
The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

And also when I add `method('PATCH')` instead of `method('PUT')`, I get this:

```
The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

So what is going wrong here?

When is the proper time for using PUT and PATCH methods and how to properly use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's standard to use post request when we are storing something for the first time and put/patch request when we are updating something. you can use post request in both though.
but html form method accepts either get or post request. you can't use put/patch/delete on form method attribute. we use method spoofing to use those request with form using method('PUT') which creates a new input field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

this determines the form request type. but for this to work your form submit url needs to be declared as a put route (patch if you want to use patch request)

```
Route::put('wallets/update/{wallet}','Wallet\WalletController@update')->name('updateWallet');
```

changing method in form won't change your defined route type. you have to change it yourself. you have to determine which type of request you will use and both form and route have to use the same type of request.

Answer (score 0):

When you change method in form at blade file, You must to change method in route file:

```
Route::put('wallets/update/{wallet}','Wallet\WalletController@update')->name('updateWallet');
```

And change method put in form:

```
<form>
   {{ method_field('PUT') }}
</form>
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using it this way, I mean, what's the difference and which one is better?

Comment: So `method('PUT')`  does not change the route method ? When should I use `method('PUT')` ?